# How do I find only the sum of null values in columns which have null values ignoring the ones with zero null values?

Tags: python, pandas, null

```
df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

can give us the null values, but it shows all columns, even the ones without any nulls. I want the columns with null values and also the counts in them.
Sum of nulls:

```
A 2
B 0
C 3
D 1
```

I have tried this already using below code. Is there a better way to do it?

```
df[df.columns[df.isnull().any()]].isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Result:

```
A 2
B 3
D 1
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort by column name or by the number of nulls?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain it with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html)/[`ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) :

```
df.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False).loc[lambda s: s.ne(0)]

C    3
A    2
D    1
dtype: int64
```

Input used :

```
print(df)

     A    B   C    D
0  NaN  bar NaN  foo
1  NaN  baz NaN  NaN
2  foo  qux NaN  baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for a one-liner, but I would just do:

```
nulls = df.isnull().sum()
nulls[nulls > 0].sort_values(ascending=False)
```